# How can I show a new component when the resolution is phone?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a foreign website and I'm happy with my result in the PC view but I would like the buttons to be changed to a selector on the phone

[the view on pc:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bARrL.png)

[in phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cb5NE.png)

please help i'm a bit desperate

Comment: you'll learn a lot by searching for `responsive reactjs` - there's a lot of ways to achieve what you want in just the first page of results

Comment: I think these three packages ([react-useragent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-useragent), [react-responsive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive) and [react-responsive-breakpoints](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-breakpoints)) might be helpful

Comment: On one of our earlier projects, we were able to use `media query` to show different UI based on the dimension. Further, if one uses something like `Material UI` - there are specific-ways (such as `theme.breakpoints`) to achieve the same objective.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the responsive property(means media queries). You can refer to this article Sofia.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp
As for particular width, you can specify properties. Here width is defined for phones and desktops.
As for a particular media query you can set style to be none in which you don't want to show that block and then you can do vice versa.

Comment: what is *"the responsive property"*?

Comment: @Bravo @ media only screen and (max-width: 600px) I meant this  . Why do you devote me to that?

Comment: @Bravo I am new here you can teach me that.

Comment: it's your answer, you said *you can use the responsive property* and now you want me to teach you what your phrase means? And don't assume who "devoted" you - two "devotes", means two people did it, doesn't mean I was one of them